# router modem tp link extender

Tags: router, modem

I currently rent and share router with 2 neighbors next door.  The router is in their place.  I often lose signal or it's not strong enough for me to stream on my 4k tv.  I am not close enough to hook up to the home router with any cabble/ethernet..

Can I buy a router/modem combo and hook it to the tp link extender in order to "Use" the wifi so it is stronger at my place?

We are all on the same billing that the landlord has set up for the property.

I really need to figure this out.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Wi-Fi range extenders cut the speed by at least half because they cannot send and receive at the same time.

Comment: You could try installing a wireless access point (or converted wireless router) at a location (in your apartment) that can receive the best signal possible, and then run Ethernet cable(s) to the TV and other PCs/laptops.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of factors that could be at play when saying you are having trouble streaming 4K content:

- **Speed of content provider.**  If you're streaming 4K media from some pirated website, then they probably aren't pushing that out at a very good speed
- **Speed of the internet connection.**  If the household doesn't have a high-speed (for 4K, I'd say minimum 70Mbps, but even 100Mbps might be slow)
- **Speed of the modem.**  If they have a regular old modem, chances are you're looking at speeds of 100Mbps, not Gigabit
- **Speed of the wireless router.**  That regular old modem has a wifi antenna built in, or they plugged in a separate router.  In the case of the router, throughput can become a factor.  Either way, connecting wirelessly tends to be slower than a wired connection.  And, even if they had a Gigabit modem, it might then experience a bottleneck back down when it comes to the router/antenna.
- **Signal strength.**  Here's the thing you were focusing on.  If you're not getting a good signal, packets are being dropped.  Yes, there are things that you can do to extend the range of the signal (access points, extenders, etc), but the signal you're seeing is your connection to that access point ... it still needs a good signal itself.  Distance isn't the only factor in signal issues.  Think about what an antenna does, and think about the materials used to build buildings ... what's in your walls?  Signal clarity dies when it has to go through canary wire like this in your drywall/plaster/concrete/brick:
  [image: wire mesh, canary wire, chicken wire, rebar]
- **Throughput.** Even if signal strength were your only issue, and you found a good spot for an access point, you still have a throughput issue of adding another device (modem -> wifi -> repeater -> you).
- **Traffic.** You're not the only one using the internet.  If you look at the devices, chances are there are lots just connected, hanging out idle, doing updates, sending stats, etc.  Printers, phones, fire sticks, are some devices we don't think about.  It all adds up to a certain amount of plaque on the artery wall that is your internet connection.  On top of that, you're sharing it with other people.  They have full access to the network, and probably are taking full advantage.
- **Bands and channels.** The point of bands and channels is to split up internet traffic.  People should be using both their 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands.  On the 5Ghz band, usually is where you'd connect a stationary receiver that's optimally placed for signal: fairly close, but not too close to the router.  Sometimes the band is even called SSID.media by default, because stationary devices usually do streaming.  Modern routers have dual or tri-bands for a reason; separate your devices between both bands for optimal traffic.
  Channels matter, for the same reason.  People like to be on certain channels: 1,6,11 are common ones for the b/g/n 2.4GHz because they're the only ones that don't overlap.  But those are router settings you may not have access to use, and they only really matter if you've got other competing wifi networks.
- **Your device.** Your device could just be slow, or connecting to the router over an older protocol.  My 802.11g devices are slower than my 802.11n devices.  Your device also has idle stuff eating away at its own bandwidth ([The Great Suspender](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjTurfMlMDcAhWmiOAKHRX4D1EQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fthe-great-suspender%2Fklbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AOvVaw2yk1xbxV4Hx8WOhZNLd5tp)(Chrome) and [Tab Suspender (Tab Unloader)](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/tab-suspender-tab-unloader/)(Opera) and [Auto Unload Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-unload-tab/)(Firefox) can help with this)